# PHP form creates a Postgresql entry when web page is opened. How can this be prevented?

Tags: php, html, sql, postgresql

I have a php/html script to update my postgresql database. The form works alright, that is it inserts data into the database. Problem is that each time I open the web page to do an insert an empty entry is created into the database. I have tried to add a "SELECT setval(...)" to repair the sequence. This did have the effect of getting rid of empty rows it does however not prevent the sequence to get out of line. This is what I have got sofar:

```
.
.
.
<?php
$db = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=crewdb user=postgres password=XXXXXX");
$query1 = "INSERT INTO access(access_name) VALUES ('$_POST[access_name]')";
$result1 = pg_query($query1);
$query2 = "SELECT setval('access_accessid_seq', (SELECT MAX(accessid) FROM access))";
$result2 = pg_select($query2);
pg_close($db)
?>
```

However the problem still is not solved. I get a table like this:

```
 accessid |             access_name              
----------+--------------------------------------
        1 | good ride on mower access throughout
        2 | n\a
        3 | no ride on mower acces
        4 | partial ride on mower acces
        5 | fenced off
        7 | Obtacles
```

As you can see accessid is out of wack. Does anyone know how to solve this problem in the most efficient way?
Table specs are:

```
  Column    |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |           Default            | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------+---------+-----------+----------+------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 accessid    | integer |           | not null | generated always as identity | plain    |              | 
 access_name | text    |           | not null |                              | extended |              |
```

I am a bit new to this so thanks for your help.

Comment: Side note: Learn to use parameterized queries ASAP. Your program is open to SQL injection!

Comment: Just add an `if (isset($_POST['access_name'])) { ... }` around the code; when you first open the page it won't be set.

Comment: Thanks Nick for your reply, I am however not sure how to apply exactly what you have written. What should go in { ... } ? Sorry I am really new to PHP.